# Hypothesis testing for a population proportion

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

I’m learning Hypothesis testing for the population proportion and I have a problem. For example, in one YouTube video it said:
$H_0: p=0.3,$
$H_1: p>0.3.$
With $n=10.$
Significance level 1%.
Number of success $X=8.$
And then it just told the result, not the process, of calculating the p. It says: $P(X>=8)=0.0016.$

And here is how I did it:

Mean = $np=3.$
Standard error = $\sqrt{n(0.3)(0.7)}=1.44.$
$Z=(8-3)/1.44=3.47.$
And then I put the z on the table and it gives me the probability of 0.0002602 which is different from the result shown on the video.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your calculation uses a normal approximation that is very unreliable when the number of successes is small (8 is very small). The approximation is archaic and should not be used because exact methods can be done in software with no effort. I don't know why textbooks persist with the approximation as it just adds confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Under $H_0: p=.3,$ the number $X$ of Successes in ten trials has $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10, p=.3).$ Then $P(X \ge 8) = 1 - P(X \le 7) = 0.0016.$
In R:

```
1 - pbinom(7, 10, .3)
[1] 0.001590386
```

This is an exact computation. I'm not sure I'd want to use a normal approximation for $n$ as small as $10$ and $p$ so far from $1/2.$ But here's how I would do it (starting with a continuity correction).

$$P(X \ge 8) = P(X > 7.5) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} > \frac{7.5 -3}{1.45} = 3.10\right)\\ \approx P(Z > 3.10) =  0.00096.$$

Because we're looking at very small probabilities in the far tail
and because the normal approximation to this binomial distribution
is marginal, I'm not surprised to see a variety of P-values
in the neighborhood of $0.001$---all of them plenty small to reject $H_0$
at the 1% level.

[I didn't check the arithmetic in your answer, a normal approximation without a continuity correction. But it seems reasonable. Check
your arithmetic and use of the table once more, but my guess is
you did nothing "wrong." There are several choices of method. However, the best answer is the exact binomial one.]

```
x = 0:10;  pdf=dbinom(x,10,.3)
 plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=2, col="blue")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 7.5, col="red", lty="dotted")
 curve(dnorm(x, 3, 1.45), add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in your calculation you’ve got 0.00096 not 0.0016! What you’ve done is not clear to me. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: The point is that the **exact** binomial value of $P(X \ge 8) = 0.001590386,$ which rounds to 0.0016, whereas the somewhat mediocre normal approximation is $ \approx P(Z > 3.10) = 0.00096.$ At best, one rarely gets more than about two decimal places of accuracy from a normal approximation. So rounding to 0.001 is just a way to say "pretty small". // Roughly speaking normal aprx to binomial should not be used unless $np$ and $n(1-p)$ both exceed $5$--more than 5 for $p$ far from $1/2.$ The fig illustrates the less-than-grear fit of normal to binomial in this case. Don't know method video used.